# Hanoi: 1.8 million VND taxi fare?

Tags: taxis, vietnam

I got an ABC taxi from Hanoi night market at 19:00 to the Airport terminal 2. It seemed legit: clean, with the sign on top and all. Followed the meter and got a receipt.

He charged me 1.8 million VND, so obviously that was a scam.

How did I got cheated? Was it a counterfeit ABC taxi or a fake/hacked meter?

Edit : Found the answer... It was in a fact a COUNTERFEIT taxi !!
It even made the local news : http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/du-khach-phap-di-taxi-du-tu-pho-co-ra-noi-bai-het-21-trieu-dong-20171006164024103.htm

Comment: According to XE.com, 1.8 million VND is about 80 USD. I have no idea what distance was travelled or what you'd normally expect a taxi in Vietnam to cost; what makes this "obviously" a scam?

Comment: Price should be around 4-500K, so likely he took a longer route to run up the bill.

Comment: I’ve heard about counterfeit taxi in Hanoi. Anyway, can you tell us where your pick up point was? A normal trip from downtown of Hanoi to the airport should cost you about 500k VND for traditional taxi. Mai Linh and Grab often offers a fixed price  package for 250k VND

Comment: We cannot say how exactly you got cheated. However you can rephrase this into asking about reliable ways to get a taxi without getting scammed.